# Can someone explain what is going on with this array?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I am quite confused on how my array is formed. This is what is written to make the array.

```
public class TestProgram {

public static final Room[] rooms = new Room[]
{
  new Room ("GARDEN0001", "NorthWest Garden View", 45.00),
  new Room ("GARDEN0002", "SouthEast Garden View", 65.0),
  new Room ("GARDEN0003", "North Garden View", 35),
  new Room ("GARDEN0004", "South Garden View", 52),
  new Room ("GARDEN0005", "West Garden View", 35),
  new Room ("GARDEN0006", "East Garden View", 35)
};
```

and I think the data comes from this class:

```
public class Room {
    public Room(String roomId, String description, double dailyRate){
        this.roomId = roomId;
        this.description = description;
        this.dailyRate = dailyRate;
        this.status = 'A';
    }
```

Us this a way of declaring an array from a constructor from another class or something? I am pretty confused but it works.

Can someone explain to me why is it written as `Room[] rooms = new Room[]`?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java

Comment: I am not really sure what you are confused about. Can you give us a comparison of what you thought how an array is usually "formed"?

Comment: You can write more simply `Room[] rooms = { new Room(...), ...};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inline initialization of an array.

"Normally" you would declare an array of certain length and then initialize it or put inside the relevant data (maybe in a loop). However, it can be done in one line, like here - an easier example would be:

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{2, 3, 5};
```

Here we have the same case, just the "numbers" are Room objects (each created and initialized here) and not int numbers.

Additionally, pay attention that the array is final - once you assign something to it, that's it (you can change the data in the array, but not its length - or change it to point do a different array). If your data is final - it's clearer to assign it all at once.

Lastly, it's static - you cannot do it in a constructor, unless you make sure it's NULL (the first time it will work, but every other after that will fail, since you'd be trying to reassign a common final object).

All in all, inline declaration and initialization of a final static array. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Breaking it down:

```
Room[] rooms
```

Declares a static field (a class variable) with name `rooms` and type `Room[]` which is an array of `Room` objects.

```
= new Room[] {new Room...};
```

Initializes the array with `Room` objects and also defines the array's size (which in java can not be changed).

Answer (score 0):

Here you declare and initialize an `array` of Room. Look -

```
Room rooms[] // declaration of 'Room' array
```

After that -

```
new Room[]
{
  new Room ("GARDEN0001", "NorthWest Garden View", 45.00),
  new Room ("GARDEN0002", "SouthEast Garden View", 65.0),
  new Room ("GARDEN0003", "North Garden View", 35),
  new Room ("GARDEN0004", "South Garden View", 52),
  new Room ("GARDEN0005", "West Garden View", 35),
  new Room ("GARDEN0006", "East Garden View", 35)
}; //initialization of the array.
```

Now here you `Room` is created with the array element you mentioned here and get the size of 6. You array declaration and initialization is actually equivalent to the following code snippet -

```
int[] intArray = new int[]{11,222,333, 444};
```

And yes your data into the array `rooms` come through Room class constructor. And look the `Room` object created by this -`new Room ("GARDEN0001", "NorthWest Garden View", 45.00)` will be found in at `room[0]`. Similarly -

```
room[1] <-- new Room ("GARDEN0002", "SouthEast Garden View", 65.0)
room[2] <-- new Room ("GARDEN0003", "North Garden View", 35)
room[3] <-- new Room ("GARDEN0004", "South Garden View", 52)
room[4] <-- new Room ("GARDEN0005", "West Garden View", 35)
room[5] <-- new Room ("GARDEN0006", "East Garden View", 35)
```